# A link error in c++

Tags: c++

I have a question about using Visual Studio to compile c++ codes. 
    I created 3 projects: A, B and C. A and B were created as dynamic library, while C was created
    as static library. There are 3 classes, with one defined in each project.

ClassA is defined in the project A:

```
ClassA
{
public
testA();
};
```

ClassB is defined in the project B.

```
ClassB: public ClassC
{
public:
testB();
};
```

ClassC is defined in the project C.

```
ClassC
{
public:
testC();

};
```

In Visual Studio, A has a dependency on B, and B has a dependency on C. But A doesn't have dependency on C.
Also the implementation of ClassA::testA is:

```
ClassA::testA ()
{
ClassB b;
b.testC();
}
```

When I build project A, I got a link error which complained external symbol of testC can't be found.
How can I solve this issue without creating dependency between A and C?

Comment: @BobbyDigital Read again: `When I build project A, I got a link error which complained external symbol of testC can't be found. How can I solve this issue without creating dependency between A and C?`

Comment: A depends on C (indirectly through B). There's no getting around that given the way you set up the description.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: It must have been edited afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependency of A on C whether you like it or not. Having B in the middle enforces this.

The immediate fix is to link in B or else write correct code to dynamic link it.

As a tip keep your interfaces C and not C++ - it makes a library more useful and likely to work. In this example it would also make it more obvious why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

B most certainly has a dependency on C.  Indirectly from A.

You can't link A without B. And since B inherits from C, A implicitly depends on C.  The compiler/linker needs to pull in the constructor of C into the project in order for it to resolve all the dependencies of A.